# Basic Qt5 UI with button

Tags: c++, comparative-review, pointers, heap, qt

I have the following Qt class:
**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT
QPushButton* m_button;
public:
    explicit MainWindow();
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() {
    auto main_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    m_button = new QPushButton("Press me");
    main_layout->addWidget(m_button);
    setLayout(main_layout);
    connect(m_button, &QPushButton::pressed, [this] {
        m_button->setText("Presse me again");
    });
}
```

It features a button which once pressed will change its text to "Press me again". I use a lambda function and I am capturing by copy `this` to access the button inside the lambda.

As the QPushButton is allocated on the heap, I think that making it a class member is an unnecessary step. My question: Are there any drawbacks if I instead use it as a local pointer which I would capture by copy in the `connect` lambda ? It would look like this:

**mainwindow.h**

```
class MainWindow : public QWidget {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow();
};
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow() {
    auto main_layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    auto button = new QPushButton("Press me");
    main_layout->addWidget(button);
    setLayout(main_layout);
    connect(button, &QPushButton::pressed, [button] { // I am copying the button's address here
        button->setText("Presse me again");
    });
}
```

One thing to note: Qt manages the destruction of all Qt classes automatically, so no need to call the button's destructor later if I understood correctly [this conversation](https://forum.qt.io/topic/24451/when-to-call-destructor).